# CAD file to polygon Using feature to polygon

Tags: arcpy, polygon, convert, cad

I have cad layer file and I want to use `feature to polygon`. I want use arcpy to do this but it dosnt work.

```
import acrpy
arcpy.env.MResolution = 0
arcpy.env.MTolerance = 0
arcpy.env.outputZValue = 0
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"
arcpy.env.ZResolution = "0 Meters"
arcpy.env.ZTolerance = "0 Meters"
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Moayedian.MHD\Desktop\test1\6007-6-343\cad"
land1 = r"C:\Users\Moayedian.MHD\Desktop\test1\6007-6-343\cad\land1.dxf Polygon"
output = r"C:\Users\Moayedian.MHD\Desktop\test1\6007-6-343\GiS\land1\new_land"
arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management = (land1,output)
```

Comment: What is the error? Did you try the standalone GP tool to validate? How about converting the drawing to FGDB using the conversion tool(https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/using-the-cad-to-geodatabase-tool.htm)
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013062#:~:text=Open%20the%20ArcCatalog%20window%20from,select%20it%20as%20the%20input.
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/using-python-to-load-cad-data.htm

Comment: As Yogesh Chavan says, it would be good to see the error. Also, if you have copied that code in directly from your script you might be missing a \ in land1 variable where you have a space between land1.dxf and Polygon, more than likely needs to be land1\Polygon.

Comment: @Clubdebambos. I useed arc catalog for cad file location. as you know each cad file have some type of layers(annotation,point,Polygon,...). I need polygon type. I will edit my code to land1/Polygon. I hope it work.

Comment: @YogeshChavan. I had no errors and no output. yes I tried with GP It's work properly. I dragged polygon cad file and It's work. but I want to use with arcpy. how we must put cad file in `land1`?as you see my `land1` feature based on arc catalog. Is it correct way to put cad file in in_feature tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import arcpy
land1 = r"C:\Users\Moayedian.MHD\Desktop\test1\6007-6-343\cad\land1.dxf\Polygon"
output = r"C:\Users\Moayedian.MHD\Desktop\test1\6007-6-343\GiS\land1\new_land.shp"
arcpy.management.FeatureToPolygon(land1,output)
```

1. Spell arcpy correctly when importing
2. Backslash between dxf and polygon
3. Call FeatureToPolygon correctly
4. Add the .shp to the new_land if exporting to a shapefile in the land1 folder